# How to rendering partials within a partials in middleman

Tags: ruby, templates, haml, partials, middleman

I have some Haml partials, many of which contain the boilerplate

`.container
    .row
      .col-lg-12`

When I try to abstract that out ala `= partial "site_section"`, I get:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input end;end;end;end
```

I'm using ruby 2.2.2.

How do I render a Haml partial within a Haml partial in Middleman?

Thanks

**update**
This is apparently some kind of special case dealing with my partial (above).  I have other partials-within-partials rendering just fine.

**update**
With respect to this [this repo](http://github.com/chischaschos/middleman-test), the layout would actually be:

_site_section:

`.container
    .row
      .col-lg-12`

_nested_section:

```
= partial "site_section"
  MOAR (nested) HAML
```

index.haml:

`=partial "nested_section"`

Comment: Can you post your file `_site_section.haml`?

Comment: That's it, above: `.container` etc

Comment: @acsmith there's a bounty, tell your friends.

Comment: I just tried but could not reproduce it , look at https://github.com/chischaschos/middleman-test. Is that the way you are using it?

Comment: @chischaschos thanks i replied to you above in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way HAML works the following is invalid:

```
= partial "site_section"
  MOAR (nested) HAML
```

If you want to add more text or HAML then you can achieve it for example by putting the text at the same level of the previous line

```
= partial "site_section"
MOAR (nested) HAML
```

Or nesting it within a div:

```
= partial "site_section"
.more   
  MOAR (nested) HAML
```

So If what you are trying to do is to nest extra HAML to the output of the *site_section* partial, then you have to put the nested extra HAML in the nested partial:

```
.container
  .row
    .col-lg-12
      = partial 'nested_stuff'
= partial 'nested_stuff'
```

Hope this helps, I updated the [repo with the working example](https://github.com/chischaschos/middleman-test).

Comment: putting it on the same level as the previous line doesn't work.  the styling of "site_section" is not applied to the partial.  nesting it within a dive (`.more`), also on the next line, doesn't work, for the same exact reason.  your third example doesn't make any sense to me.  it wouldn't give me what i'm looking for.

Comment: Oh then I think I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, what would be the expected output html?

Comment: thanks for hanging in there.  I'm trying to abstract out the
 `.container
    .row
      .col-lg-12`
into its own partial (`_site_section.haml`), for use in other partials.  each partial would be able to express additional content, nested under `_site_section`.  The equivalent would be what I already have working, which is just to repeat
 `.container
    .row
      .col-lg-12`
in ever partial, followed by new content nested underneath.

Comment: Seems like the only way could be to provide a block to the partial as in https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/1099. My example would then become https://github.com/chischaschos/middleman-test/blob/master/test/source/_nested_section.haml#L2.

Comment: again, thanks for hanging in there.  adding the `do` block doesn't yield text or haml, even if prefixed with a `puts`.  this could possibly be because the `mixin` functionality was never actually merged with `middleman` `master`.  even if one could use it, you'd have to use `=mixin`, etc.  that link is good, though.  it looks like there might be a solution possible from the building blocks he gives where he says "vanilla `partial`".