# How to specify Middleman's partials directory globally?

Tags: ruby, templates, haml, partial-views, middleman

In Middleman, I can specify that I want to yield a partial located in a specific directory by using

```
= partial "partials/imports/js"
```

I'd like Middleman to know in which directory my partials reside.  How do I modify config.rb so that I can just use `= partial "js"`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of tacking a tag to the front or end of your question's title, where it hangs completely outside the flow of the sentence, either work it into the flow of the sentence or rely on SO's built-in tags. It's not necessary to name "Middleman" in the title as the tags are used by the search engines and by SO to help people find the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the default partials directory by using `set` in your `config.rb` like this:

```
set :partials_dir, 'partials/imports'
```

Comment: Thanks, can you add multiple directories?  e.g. `'partials', 'partials/imports'`

Comment: I don't think it's possible to set multiple directories, why don't you just create sub-directory inside partials?

Comment: Done, thanks! If you would, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752830/rendering-partials-within-partials-in-middleman?noredirect=1#comment47644292_29752830 .

Comment: As of Middleman v4: "Removed partials_dir config option. Please reference all partials from the source/ directory. partial 'partials/my-partial' would map to source/partials/_my-partial.erb."